# How to use methods from other Controllers in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

In my app I use a InvoicesController which handles the creation of invoices that can originate from several other Models. After some method is called in another method that leads to the generation of a new invoice, I want to call the create() method in the InvoicesController but also need the relevant parameters. I want to centralize this, because the create() method also contains the logic of informing the customer that a new invoice is ready for payment (with EmailComponent, since I cannot use this in Invoice Model).

Any ideas or best practices for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

normally you would do that method in the model (i mean creation of invoice) and in the controller the before and after (getting params and giving answer) and that way you can easily reuse the creation con the invoice... anyway you can always use

```
App::import('Controller', 'Posts');
$post = new PostsController();
$post->myFunction();
```

To get to use another controller function.

Also you may do a Lib with some functions you want to reuse, but in your case i will do it with the model

Hope this helps you

Comment: As api55 says, your invoices should really be built in the model. Best practice in CakePHP is fat Models and Skinny Controllers: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/06/another-way-to-think-about-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

If you use it that much in other controllers, consider putting that function in the app_controller and you`ll always be able to access it with $this->Function in any other controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your reusable code in a model method!

by the way:
you can use EmailComponent in a model. I do that for many years now. With 2.0 it gets even easier to do so. 
But in 1.3 simply use

```
$Email = new EmailComponent(new Controller()));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-classes 
it works in cakephp2.0 with

```
App::import('PostsController', 'Controller');
```